# Magento2 Issue after disabling core Magento_Sales

Tags: magento2, sales

PHP Fatal error: Cannot use "parent" when current class scope has no parent in /var/www/html/sm_market4/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Api/OrderRepositoryInterface/Interceptor.php on line 22

Getting the error after disabling core Magento_Sales

Answer (score 0):

Check after run below command

```
rm -rf generated/

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: not working already tried